# Entity Framework generating predicate function outside the query

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF with model separated from the DTO, and as I need to implement the same functions for many classes (`GetByPrimarykey`, `GetBy`, `GetAll` and etc), I thought it would be nice to have abstract class:

```
       protected List<T> GetBy(Func<T, bool> func)
        {
            return WorkingSet.Where(func).ToList();
        }
        protected T GetFirstBy(Func<T, bool> func)
        {
            return WorkingSet.FirstOrDefault(func);
        }
        public virtual T GetByPrimaryKey(K key)
        {
           return WorkingSet.FirstOrDefault(GetByKeyPredict(key));
        }
```

And then to simply implement the predicte  functions in the implementing classes:

```
protected override Func<MyType, bool> GetByKeyPredict(int key)
{
   return (c=> c.MyTypeId==key);
}
```

The problem is that when I run SQL Server Profiler, I see the select doesn't have where cause. If I override the `GetByPrimaryKey` function:

```
public override MyTypeGetByPrimaryKey(int key)
{
    return WorkingSet.FirstOrDefault(s => s.MyTypeId== key);
}
```

The query is fine but, I really need the predict to work as we the `GetBy` functions are proven to be very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use Expression to be able to get the SQL translation. e.g.

```
protected List<T> GetBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> func)
        {
            return WorkingSet.Where(func).ToList();
        }
        protected T GetFirstBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> func)
        {
            return WorkingSet.FirstOrDefault(func);
        }
```

The goal in your case is to use the methods from IQueryable, instead of IEnumerable, because the methods of IQueryable get translated to SQL.
I hope that helps.

Comment: Helps, solves the question and explains it well great answer :)